# В Каменец-Подольском или в Каменце-Подольском?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, склонение, названия

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склонять — в Каменец-Подольском или в Каменце-Подольском? И каким правилом это объяснить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: _Aer: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый..._ === Я **исчерпывающего** ответа пока в этой теме не увидел (несмотря на четыре плюса, появившихся к этому времени у ответа _Arina_). А потому посоветовал бы **huyuffie** не торопиться с принятием решения.

Comment: @ slava1947, а что вас не устроило в ответе Арины? В словаре на Грамоте.ру сконяется только вторая часть. Каменец-Подольский, -ого (город) Других рекомендаций пока найти не удалось.

Comment: _Серж: а что вас не устроило в ответе Арины?_ === В первую очередь -- неправильная аргументация...

Comment: Какая именно? Ведь Арина ссылается на справочник Розенталя. Что делаем и мы при ответах.

Comment: _Серж: Какая именно? Ведь Арина ссылается на справочник Розенталя..._ === Ну да, ссылается... Только у Розенталя НИЧЕГО про **Каменец-Подольский**-то ведь не сказано. Почитайте повнимательнее.

Comment: Как не сказано? Цитата полностью соответствует источнику. Вы, наверное, не заметили.

Comment: Правильно, видимо, так, как говорит большинство местных. Более поздним письменным источникам остаётся только подвести под это произношение обьяснения и придумать правила.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: в Каменец-Подольском.

Розенталь: [XXXVI. ФОРМЫ ИМЕН СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm)

6)  В сложных географических названиях первая часть в одних случаях склоняется, в других – остается без изменений; ср.: в Орехове-Зуеве, в Покровском-Стрешневе, во Владимире-Волынском – в Каменец-Подольске, в Гусь-Хрустальном.

Comment: @ Arina, хотя это не относится к вопросу непосредствено. Но все же. В словаре собственных имен на Грамоте склоняется только вторая часть: в Орехово-Зуево. То же говорится на Грамме.ру и на Грамоте.ру. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы дополнили информацию. Рекомендацию Розенталю, наверно, можно считать устаревшой или опечаткой.

Comment: Нормы склонения топонимов могут меняться, возможно, в названии Каменец-Подольский склоняются обе части, в текстах встречаются оба варианта. Каменец-Подольский — административный центр Каменец-Подольского района. Есть еще Каменец-Подольская крепость. Вроде бы не надо склонять для однообразия названий.  С другой стороны, город иногда называют просто Каменец, тогда его надо склонять.  Что касается Орехово-Зуева, то это проблема топонимов на ОВ/ЕВ и ИН/ЫН, Например, по правилам - в Строгине, но так никто не говорит. Также: Нелегкий  выбор предстоит жителям Орехово-Зуева, иногда - в Орехово-Зуево.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы город назывался *Каменец-Подольск* (а так *Каменец-Подольский* когда-то и назывался), то правильным был бы вариант, приведённый Розенталем:

***в Каменец-Подольске***.

Но вопрос-то поставлен о склонении названия города *Каменец-Подольский* (а не *Каменец-Подольск!*):

> в *Каменец-Подольском* или в *Каменце-Подольском?*

**На сегодняшний день оба варианта правильны.** Говорят и *в Каменец-Подольском*, и *в Каменце-Подольском*. И оба варианта поддерживаются авторитетными словарями.

[***"Русский орфографический словарь"***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x) под ред. Лопатина рекомендует склонять только вторую часть этого названия. И потому правильно:

***в Каменец-Подольском.***

Но другой не менее авторитетный словарь (включённый, кстати,  приказом Минобразования РФ от 08 июня 2009 г. N 195 в "Список грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации") —

***«Грамматический словарь русского языка»*** А. А. Зализняка рекомендует склонение обеих частей этого названия, а потому правилен и второй вариант:

***в Каменце-Подольском.***

Из словаря Зализняка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: в Каменец-Подольском

Вот что говорится в книге

[СОВРЕМЕННЫЙ РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК  ЛЕКСИКА,ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЯ,МОРФОЛОГИЯ. РАХМАНОВА ЛЮДМИЛА ИГОРЕВНА,СУЗДАЛЬЦЕВА ВЕРА НИКОЛАЕВНА](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/125.htm)

Что касается неоднословных топонимов, то они склоняются по-разному в зависимости от того, являются ли они обычными для русского языка синтаксическими сочетаниями или нет. Во-первых склоняются все слова, точнее, все слова, которые поддаются склонению, соответствующему данной синтаксической конструкции: "в Вышнем Волочке (в Новом Орлеане)", "под Нижним Тагилом", "на Дальнем Востоке", "во Франкфурте-на-Майне" и т.д. **Во-вторых, т.е. в тех неоднословных названиях, которые воспринимаются как синтаксически неразложимые, склоняется лишь последний элемент (если он поддается склонению):** "в Порт-Саиде (в Нью-Йорке)", "вдоль Сьерра-Невады", "предгорья Копет-Дага", **"в Каменец-Подольском"**